# Self activating iMac after set standby mode

Tags: macos, virus, remote-access

I set today my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017) to standby and go shopping. After I come back after about 20 min., the Mac was active but the backgroundscreen was not the one I set to. It was a uni color lightgray. I have to go into another room and after I come back, some seconds later, the Mac was in standby mode again. Also very creepy...

There are no special settings in Prefs->Energy saving for this behaviour.

I have seen this behavior before once. So I ask me what can this be. Is it a bug in MacOS? Can this be a malicious attack? I remember that TeamView will change the background if the computer ist remote controlled. And how can I inspect this?

Next the system.log. About 08:50 I set the standby mode and about 09:05 I come back. There were activities in between.

```
Oct 19 08:45:30 Adminisrators-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Oct 19 08:54:48 Adminisrators-iMac syslogd[41]: ASL Sender Statistics
Oct 19 08:54:48 Adminisrators-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd[99]): Service exited due to SIGALRM | sent by kernel_task[0]
Oct 19 08:55:03 Adminisrators-iMac xpcproxy[723]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Oct 19 08:55:03 Adminisrators-iMac timed[81]: settimeofday({0x5f8d3847,0x5ea43}) == 0
Oct 19 08:55:27 Adminisrators-iMac bluetoothd[97]: notify name "com.apple.bluetooth.sensorTracking.stateChanged" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak
Oct 19 09:05:46 Adminisrators-iMac syslogd[41]: ASL Sender Statistics
Oct 19 09:05:46 Adminisrators-iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd[724]): Service exited due to SIGALRM | sent by kernel_task[0]
Oct 19 09:05:54 Adminisrators-iMac xpcproxy[730]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Oct 19 09:06:05 Adminisrators-iMac timed[81]: settimeofday({0x5f8d3add,0x17c54}) == 0
Oct 19 09:09:25 Adminisrators-iMac xpcproxy[735]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 529: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the so-called [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032), which is part of MacOS (as a feature, not as a bug). Please turn this feature off and observe again.

Comment: This explains the activities in the log, but not the activation of the screen with another background. This can only done by: "Wireless base stations can wake your Mac using Wake on Wireless." [(Power Nap)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032). I use a modem with WLAN and the only powered device at this point was my iPhone. Can my phone activate it? And why should it do this, the sync is a background task? And why don't it do this every time, when I come back?